# Azure DeploymentGroup access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, devops

I'm trying to register my Deployment group in windows server but I'm getting below error

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

[image]

but I have admin access in server.

Comment: wrong pat? not enough permissions? no idea

Comment: I edited out the screenshot containing your PAT. In general, don't provide screenshots -- provide text.

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxx) or Server (http://servername/tfs)? It seems you are using Azure DevOps Server, if this is the case, which account did you use for the agent service? a PAT or basic username and password?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - yes we use Azure Devops and I tried with PAT only . I dont know how to try with username/pwd

Comment: @DanielMann - Thank you:-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Azure DevOps Server. Please check if the 'Team Foundation Background Job Agent service' is running or not. Besides, you can try to deploy the agent with a PAT, then clean caches on your client machine and try it again to check if that works.

Comment: i tried with PAT only and please guide how to check TFS Job Agent

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps **Service** (dev.azure.com/xxx) or **Server** (servername/tfs)? If you use `Server`, it's in Task Manager -- Service. In addition, check the IIS to see whether the Basic Authentication is disabled.

Comment: Thanks and I followed your steps like below.                                                                   
1.Verified that "Team Foundation Background Job Agent service" is running.                
 2.Enabled the Basic Authentication                                                               
3.Tried to deploy the agent with PAT                                                                                                                                                                                       But still i'm getting the same error .  Any idea Please?

Comment: To use PAT, Basic Authentication needs to be disabled. Which Authentication  have you enabled in IIS? Do you have any proxy server inside your network?Try use different auth type, like `Negotiate` instead of `PAT`. What's your TFS url looks like?

Comment: I tried with "Negotiate" and giving my username and password. It worked.